# ChartApi.AbstractSession:[cs_D0WAbwHFoENL] Critical error. Reason=invalid parameters, info=method: create_series

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

is there anyone who has experience about tradingview custom chart ,I try to make own symbol with own data on tradingview. but there is problem in create_series.
it always show

```
ChartApi.AbstractSession:[cs_D0WAbwHFoENL] Critical error. Reason=invalid parameters, info=method: create_series. args: "[sds_1, s1, sds_sym_1, 1h, 300, ]".
```

here is my codes

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
```

javascript code

```
function parseCSVData(csvData) {
  const lines = csvData.split('\n');
  const data = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) { // Start from 1 to skip the header
    const values = lines[i].split(',');

    const [date, time, open, high, low, close, volume] = values;

    const dateTime = new Date(`${date} ${time}`);

    data.push({
      time: dateTime.getTime(), // Use the timestamp instead of a Date object
      open: parseFloat(open),
      high: parseFloat(high),
      low: parseFloat(low),
      close: parseFloat(close),
      volume: parseFloat(volume),
    });
  }

  return data;
}

// // Replace the sample CSV data below with your own CSV data
const csvData = `
1/25/2022, 10:50:00 AM,35964.4,35964.4,35908.52,35922.24,31.63878
1/25/2022, 10:51:00 AM,35922.23,35953.93,35908.65,35952.12,25.06247
1/25/2022, 10:52:00 AM,35949.49,35964.4,35945,35961.94,13.20111

`;


const parsedData = parseCSVData(csvData);

const tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({

  widgetReady: () => {
    // Inside widgetReady

    // Inside widgetReady

    const chart = tvWidget.chart()

    chart.onChartReady(() => {

      // Now session_id will be available
      const sessionId = chart.session_id()

      console.log(sessionId)


      chart.create_series(
        sessionId,
        "s1",
        "EEC/USDT",
        "1h",
        300
      )


    })

  },

  symbol: 'EEC/USDT',
  interval: '1h',
  timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
  theme: 'light',
  style: '1',
  locale: 'en',
  enable_publishing: false,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
  withdateranges: true,
  hide_side_toolbar: false,
  allow_symbol_change: true, // Allowing symbol change
  debug: true,
  details: true,
  hotlist: true,
  fullscreen: true,
  container: 'tvchart',
 // library_path: '/charting_library.standalone.js',

  datafeed: {
    disable_quote_request: true,
    onReady: function (callback) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        callback({
          supported_resolutions: ['1h'], // Supporting only 1-hour resolution
        });
      }, 0);
    },
    resolveSymbol: function (symbolName, onSymbolResolvedCallback, onResolveErrorCallback) {
      var symbolInfo = {
        name: 'EEC/USDT',
        ticker: 'EEC/USDT',
        description: 'EEC/USDT',
        type: 'crypto',
        session: '24x7',
        exchange: 'Your Exchange',
        listed_exchange: 'Your Exchange',
        timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
        pricescale: 100,
        minmov: 1,
        has_intraday: true,
        intraday_multipliers: ['1', '60'],
        supported_resolutions: ['1h'], // Supporting only 1-hour resolution
        volume_precision: 2,
        data_status: 'streaming',
      };

      if (symbolName === 'EEC/USDT') {
        onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
      } else {
        onResolveErrorCallback('Unknown symbol');
      }
    },
    getBars: function (symbolInfo, resolution, from, to, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, firstDataRequest) {
      const timeframeInMinutes = getMinutesFromResolution(resolution);
      const ohlcData = [];
    
      // Filter and return the parsed data within the specified date range
      parsedData.forEach(bar => {
        if (bar.time >= from && bar.time <= to) {
          ohlcData.push(bar);
        }
      });
    
      // Convert the OHLC data to the requested resolution
      const bars = convertToResolution(ohlcData, timeframeInMinutes);
      onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    },
   
        
    subscribeBars: function (symbolInfo, resolution, onRealtimeCallback, subscriberUID, onResetCacheNeededCallback) {
      // You can implement real-time updates here if needed
    },
    unsubscribeBars: function (subscriberUID) {
      // Unsubscribe from real-time updates if implemented
    },
  },

    
    
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RNE1.png)

I want to make own symbol with own data chart , I have no experience in tradingview .
I find some example on google , no similar case see, Can someone help me